# Is it possible to use ethernet port for power+rs232

Tags: poe

RPi4 poe pinout has 4 output which is connected to the 4 unused ethernet cable lines. Can I use these for +,-,Rx,TX. I don't use ethernet. Rx,Tx will be connected to the header's serial port. If it is possible, it will help me to remove bulky serial connectors and separate power connectors.

Comment: why not just buy connectors of your choice and use them?  nothing says you have to run serial and power through something bulky.  you could in theory tear the network connector off a pi and wire it as such, but buying one is bound to be more cost-effective.

Comment: @Abel Hey Abel, thanks for the comment. It just looks ugly. The ethernet port is in the perfect place but I don't want to unsolder and remove it. That's all. It was a problem of art, not tech. A common problem with low quantity production.